# Android - prevent swiping/dragging on touch event

Tags: android, user-input, touch-event

I'm using the following code to detect taps on the screen, however I've noticed it responds to swipes and activates the code in the event handler several times, how do I stop this? Thanks.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    if (x < viewWidth/2)
    {
        xDir -= 10;

    }

    else
    {
        xDir += 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have read that, hence my initial code, however I still don't what what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

u should use something like this:

```
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    int x = (int)event.getX();
                    if (x < viewWidth/2) {
                       xDir -= 10;
                    }else  {
                       xDir += 10;
                    }
                } 
            }
```

note: u can use other MotionEvent flags like ACTION_DOWN ...